# How to serve different page request from same button dynamically?

Tags: jsf, navigation

I have a fix top navigation bar like [this](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/). And I have several links to pages(e.g. foods.xhtml, cars.xhtml, planes.xhtml) in side bar navigation(Like: "similar questions" side bar in stackoverflow, so its like inverted 'L').

Goal: Click on any sidebar link(from home page) and it should take me to the next page(let's say "foods.xhtml", which has list of foods) and when I click on any food it will take me to next page(let's say Sandwich.xhtml) and a back button to be created on fixed top navigation bar to navigate back tolist of foods(foods.xhtml).

Questions:

1. When I click on one sidebar link(->foods.xhtml), how can I store the
   foods.xhtml in backing bean so that when I go to sandwich.xhtml and
   want to navigate back, the "back" button on fixed navigation bar
   will point to foods.xhtml?

Note:
I want this to work for cars, planes. So the "back" button in top fixed navigation bar has different "page redirection" at different page served.

Comment: It's unnecessary to edit and say that you're developing a JSF application if you already put `[jsf]` tag on the question which would only be visited by JSF users.

Comment: BalusC is right... And if your intention is to get it to the top again, it might work against you if noting is actually added to the question...

Comment: Thanks guys. I will undo it.